# Does deleting a Twitter webhook really require me to have all related consumer credentials?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, webhooks

In the Twitter Account Activity API documentation for deleting webhooks, the following authentication requirement is listed:

*Requires Authentication    Yes (user context - all consumer and access tokens)*
*Source: [https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/api-reference/aaa-premium#delete-account-activity-all-env-name-webhooks-webhook-id](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/api-reference/aaa-premium#delete-account-activity-all-env-name-webhooks-webhook-id_)*

This would mean that when I build an application that is managing these webhooks using it's own api key and secret, and allowing multiple users to use the webhooks through their consumer key and secret, I am not allowed to shut down my webhooks if for some reason I don't have all the right consumer's access tokens handy.

I *can* force the webhook to invalidate, because I'm in control of the crc, but that's just awkward. **Is it true that I can not, in code or otherwise, delete one of my webhooks if I no longer have any of the consumer credentials used to create it?**

The example is also for a single credential, and I'm not sure how I'm supposed to send multiple credentials, especially regarding OAuth1 signing..

Comment: Good news, we literally just announced that is is now possible using just a bearer token! https://twittercommunity.com/t/new-release-account-activity-api-endpoint/127829

Comment: Wow, you built that quick! ;). Consider posting this as an answer so I can mark this resolved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, I just noticed this is just for subscriptions. Any word on the same change for webhooks?

Comment: No, the webhooks themselves are owned by the app / owner. This is just for the subscriptions. What's the use case for deleting the webhook URLs minus the user context, I'm struggling to connect that one up.

Comment: I guess the statement 'all consumer and access tokens' has thrown me off. If I need only the app and owner credentials the webhook was started with, and not those of any consumers subscribed to it, there is no issue. Otherwise it's just convenience, since I can remove all the subscriptions before stopping the webhook now anyway.

Comment: You're right; I misread your request as being about subscriptions when your core request was for the webhook itself, I apologize. So the webhook registrations belong to the app and app owner; previously, you needed user Auth to add and remove subscriptions to the webhook, but if a user revoked Auth for the app, then it would longer be possible to remove the subscription since the tokens were invalid, this we removed that requirement (today). Under what circumstances would you as app owner no longer have all 4 tokens and secrets at an app and webhook level, maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196532/discussion-between-mark-tielemans-and-andy-piper).